# SQL query for finding records where count < 2

Tags: sql

I have a table called Customer:

```
|device_id|user_id|
|   1     |   1   |
|   2     |   1   |
|   3     |   1   |
|   4     |   1   |
|   5     |   2   |
|   6     |   2   |
|   7     |   3   |
```

Now I want to return only the entries which have only 1 device per user. In this case only

```
|device_id|user_id|
|   7     |   3   |
```

Should be returned because user_id 3 is the only one with only 1 device (user_id 1 has 4, user_id 2 has 2)

How would I do that with a query?

Comment: It looks like you want the opposite, users with only one device.

Comment: yes thats what I meant sorry

Answer (score 0):

One method is `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.device_id <> t.device_id
                 );
```

You can also use aggregation:

```
select device_id, max(user_id) as user_id
from t
group by device_id
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Group by device_id will always give count of 1 for the above sample data

Answer (score 0):

We can use **group by** to group the data on the basis of user_id followed by aggregate funciton to get the count of device:

```
 SELECT device_id,user_id FROM customer where user_id IN
(
SELECT user_id from
(
SELECT user_id,count(*) FROM customer GROUP BY user_id HAVING count(*)<2
)
);
```